# Specific transpose with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have the following database example (Database), I was wondering if there is a way to give it the format of the database2 example (Database2) using python.

[image: Database]

[image: Database2]

I'm kind of new to python, i've been able to convert the original excel to a dataframe and work with them that way, but I'm stuck with this transposing since I end up getting the following

[image: Unwanted result]

I was thinking maybe there is a way to transpose if a criteria is meet, but I certainly don't know how to take this into form. I've been filling the original excel file by hand, and I really need to automatize this since there are tons of rows added constantly.

Edit: This is the code I've been using, yes i've tried melt, but something is missing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

data = pd.ExcelFile('Test3.xlsx')
sheet_names = data.sheet_names
df = pd.read_excel(data)

for tab in sheet_names:
    print('--------- ' + tab + ' -------')
    df = pd.read_excel(data)
    print(df.iloc[:5, :8])

df = pd.read_excel('Test3.xlsx') # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets
Cliente = list(df['Cliente']) 
ID = list(df['ID'])
Costo1 = list(df['Costo1'])
Margen1 = list(df['Margen1'])
Ganancia1 = list(df['Ganancia1'])
Costo2 = list(df['Costo2'])
Margen2 = list(df['Margen2'])
Ganancia2 = list(df['Ganancia2'])

lista = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Cliente': Cliente,
     'ID': ID,
     'Costo1': Costo1,
     'Margen1': Margen1,
     'Ganancia1': Ganancia1,
     'Costo2': Costo2,
     'Margen2': Margen2,
     'Ganancia2': Ganancia2
    })
print(lista)

new_df = lista.melt(id_vars=['Cliente','ID'])

new_df.variable = new_df.variable.apply(lambda x: 'Costo' if 'Costo' in x else x)
new_df.variable = new_df.variable.apply(lambda x: 'Margen' if 'Margen' in x else x)
new_df.variable = new_df.variable.apply(lambda x: 'Ganancia' if 'Ganancia' in x else x)
```

Comment: [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: where is your code? You could add data as text - ie. csv content or Python list - and then we can use it to test some ideas.

Comment: I just uploaded the code i've been using, the thing is that if I use melt it just returns a column with "Price1, price2" and what I want is a column with the type (price, margin, etc), and a column for product 1 and product 2. It seems like I will need to do it manually isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a bit of old-style Python, with just `openpyxl` and nothing else?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange

wb=load_workbook("myfile.xlsx")
ws=wb.active
tb=ws.tables["Table1"]
rng=CellRange(tb.ref)

for i,row in enumerate(rng.rows):
    if i == 0:
        outrowno = rng.max_row + 3
        currClient = ""
        currID = ""
        ws.cell(outrowno, 1).value = "Client"
        ws.cell(outrowno, 2).value = "ID"
        ws.cell(outrowno, 3).value = "Type"
        ws.cell(outrowno, 4).value = "A"
        ws.cell(outrowno, 5).value = "B"
    else:
        newClient = ws.cell(*row[0]).value
        newID = ws.cell(*row[1]).value
        if newClient != currClient or newID != currID:
            currClient = newClient
            currID = newID
            for t in range(3):
                outrowno += 1
                ws.cell(outrowno, 1).value = newClient
                ws.cell(outrowno, 2).value = newID
                ws.cell(outrowno, 3).value = ["Cost", "Margin", "Price"][t]
                ws.cell(outrowno, 4).value = ws.cell(*row[t+2]).value
                ws.cell(outrowno, 5).value = ws.cell(*row[t+5]).value

tbout = Table(displayName="Table2", ref=f"A{rng.max_row + 3}:E{outrowno}")
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium9", showFirstColumn=False,
                       showLastColumn=False, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tbout.tableStyleInfo = style
ws.add_table(tbout)
wb.save("myfile.xlsx")
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thanks!!